# performing post actions with multiple partial views in mvc3 in asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, updatepanel, partial-views

It may be repeat in question. but I need guidance for the approach to implement this scenario.
I have the controller in asp.net mvc3. I need to implement the view that contains multiple partial views. each partial view having the data transaction with database. means post data to database. I am having something like this :

```
<div >
    <div id="div1">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView1", ViewData("pv1"))
        %>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView2", ViewData("pv2")) %>
    </div>


    <div id="div3">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView3", ViewData("pv3")) %>
    </div>



    <div id="div4">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView4", ViewData("pv4")) %>
    </div>
```

Where as in Controller, i am confuse how to render respective partial view only. as other partial views should not affect except the data posting partial view. means i need update panel kind functionality. but am bit confuse how to achieve that.

**Edited :in short how to build multiple update panels on single page in mvc 3 ?**

**Consider the image :**
[image]

This image is not, what I explain in code. please understand the concept. here functionality wise in second partial view there is dropdown , which will filled up with get action always. while adding the user there should not recall getusers actions for that dropdown. Inshort all partial view should independent of each other actions. only respective partial view should get affect by certain action.

Comment: I can't quite follow what you are asking?

Comment: @Adam, in short  how to build multiple update panels on single page in mvc 3 ?

Comment: Is my question is not understandable ? am i wrong ?

Comment: I think you are looking for RenderAction, not RenderPartial, no? You want ajax forms to call an action, whose output is html. Upon postback, they will post back to those actions that rendered them. Also since you are using mvc3, why not use the razor syntax?

Comment: oh! I am not much familiar with razor in fact. and i think you caught perfect. assume there is no full page post back rather the part. Please refer the image in Question i added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Ajax forms and instruct them to update the corresponding div:

```
<div>
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div1" })) { %>
        <div id="div1">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView1", ViewData("pv1")); %>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div2" })) { %>
        <div id="div2">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView2", ViewData("pv2")); %>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div3" })) { %>
        <div id="div3">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView3", ViewData("pv3")); %>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div4" })) { %>
        <div id="div4">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("PartialView4", ViewData("pv4")); %>
        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but what should be the actions then ? will this render enclose in single action ? or respective?

Comment: That would depend on your scenario and what you are trying to achieve but basically they will return partial views.

Comment: agree, but need general approach to handle this. please review the question once, I added image and description

Comment: @RedSwan, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, what you already tried and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the multiple update panels on single page in mvc. in this scenario what should be the role of Controller and actions? That means each partial view will have separate actions or all partial view operations  should enclose with single action?

Comment: Usually the role of an action is to receive the user input under the form of a view model as action parameter, do some validations, map the view model to a domain model, pass the domain model to your service layer for performing some processing and returning the same or another view model to the view. In your case that would be a partial view since you are doing Ajax. As far as whether all partial views should post to a single action or have different actions, that would also depend on the amount of code you could centralize. Usually having different actions is preferred. But  will depend.

Comment: exactly, suppose in above scenario (image in question), there I added user just now . now i need to view some user by selecting the user name from dropdown in third partial view. now I want to delete the user from second partial view. then when action of deletion performed there should no impact on third partial view. in this way I am sending only single partial view to server. right ? but when DeleteUser action in Controller will perform, how rest of partial views will maintain the state?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *state* and what you need to maintain. But it looks indeed that your controller actions perform quite different tasks so it would be better to separate them.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and help dude. so I need to write separate actions for each partial view rather single ?

Comment: @RedSwan, according to your description that looks like more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry to say but still I am not that cleared idea, how to render the partial views within a single page in controller and action perspectives. and what need to be add in actions for render the respective partial views

Comment: @ Darin , Can you please code me the respective actions syntax, no need for business logic ofcourse it is at my end. so that i should get the idea. the code you send: i observed a main div contain entire partial views. may i know id Container div also in view then there must be the action for that div containing view. so what should be the action for outer div's view in controller ?

Comment: ...So finally we can conclude MVC is incapable to perform this scenario... shame on MVC

Comment: @RedSwan, that would be your conclusion. I cannot do any conclusions without having a concrete scenario to talk about.

Comment: well its depends, i could not figure it out so far. so i should conclude so.